# How to display the computer's current RAM usage with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ram, system-information

I want to make a Chrome extension to monitor CPU and RAM usage, but I can't find out how to get the current RAM usage of the computer. I searched on Google and didn't find anything. Eventually, I found this code below, and I tried it out to see if it works.

```js
const ramUsage = window.performance.memory;
```

But this code just prints out the RAM usage of the current web page. Is there any way to print the computer's total RAM usage with JavaScript?

Comment: `window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize` is the total memory used by JavaScript in that window.

Comment: you can only get maxium memory witch can yose chorme. in setup is 4 from 16 gb.

Comment: window.performance.memory returns an object, so you will have to parse it. Else you can use one of these.

`window.performance.memory.totalJSHeapSize`
`window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize`
`window.performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes, that does get the amount of RAM the current window is using, but I want to get the computer's total RAM usage.

Comment: Then [edit] your question so that's clear. Currently it just says "current RAM usage" which is ambiguous.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I changed my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think so that you can check all available memory in system . system configuration is private information. if it would be available then all people with 4gb of ram would get advertisement with ram offer..... but in chorme there is flag : --enable-precise-memory-info